# Wicket - Ajax PropertyListView

Tags: java, ajax, list, listview, wicket

I got some data going into my propertyListview, got a container around it but when i want to update it with Ajax it aint doing nothing ! How do i update my PropertyListview with Ajax?

*EDIT*
in the background im using JSON Parse to parse data from a weatherstation, that data can change alot, so i want to update the data in the propertyListview

```
public class WeerPanel extends Panel {

public WeerPanel(String id) throws IOException {
    super(id);

    final WeerService weerService = new WeerServiceImpl();

    PropertyListView<Weer> newview = new PropertyListView<Weer>("weer", weerService.getWeer()) {

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<Weer> item) {
            item.add(new Label("temperatuur"));
            item.add(new StaticImage("type", String.format("images/%s.png", item.getModelObject().getType())));
            item.add(new Label("omschrijving"));
        }
    };

    final WeerVoorspellingService weerVoorspellingService = new WeerVoorspellingServiceImpl();

    PropertyListView<WeerVoorspelling> hateView = new PropertyListView<WeerVoorspelling>("weersvoorspelling", weerVoorspellingService.getWeerVoorspelling()) {

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<WeerVoorspelling> item) {
            item.add(new Label("dag"));
            item.add(new StaticImage("typeVoorspelling", String.format("images/%s.png", item.getModelObject().getType())));
            item.add(new Label("minTemperatuur"));
            item.add(new Label("maxTemperatuur"));
        }
    };

    final WebMarkupContainer containerWeer = new WebMarkupContainer("containerWeer");
    containerWeer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    containerWeer.add(hateView);
    containerWeer.add(newview);
    add(containerWeer);

    add(new AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(10)) {

        @Override
        protected final void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            target.add(containerWeer);
        }
    });
}
```

}

This is some code i do in the background, its a dummy that changes the temp of the weather by a random number each time.

```
                Random r = new Random();
            int randomInt = r.nextInt(100);
            weer.add(new Weer("rain", "Mooi bewolkt", randomInt, v.getVoorspellingen()));
```

The dummy code is fine, but STILL there is nothing of a change to see at my page.... as if my the list isnt getting any new data..

*FIXED* here is the code for people that will find this handy

```
public class WeerPanel extends Panel {

    public WeerPanel(String id) {

        super(id);

        add(createContainer());

        add(new AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(10)) {
            @Override
            protected final void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                target.add(createContainer());
            }
        });
    }

    private final WebMarkupContainer createContainer() {
        final WeerService weerService = new WeerServiceImpl();

        PropertyListView<Weer> newview = null;
        try {
            newview = new PropertyListView<Weer>("weer", weerService.getWeer()) {

                @Override
                protected void populateItem(ListItem<Weer> item) {
                    item.add(new Label("temperatuur"));
                    item.add(new StaticImage("type", String.format("images/%s.png", item.getModelObject().getType())));
                    item.add(new Label("omschrijving"));
                }
            };
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        WeerVoorspellingService weerVoorspellingService = new WeerVoorspellingServiceImpl();

        PropertyListView<WeerVoorspelling> hateView = null;
        try {
            hateView = new PropertyListView<WeerVoorspelling>("weersvoorspelling", weerVoorspellingService.getWeerVoorspelling()) {

                @Override
                protected void populateItem(ListItem<WeerVoorspelling> item) {
                    item.add(new Label("dag"));
                    item.add(new StaticImage("typeVoorspelling", String.format("images/%s.png", item.getModelObject().getType())));
                    item.add(new Label("minTemperatuur"));
                    item.add(new Label("maxTemperatuur"));
                }
            };
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        WebMarkupContainer containerWeer = new WebMarkupContainer("containerWeer");
        containerWeer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        containerWeer.add(hateView);
        containerWeer.add(newview);
        addOrReplace(containerWeer);

        return containerWeer;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with your AJAX call? Swap the two listviews?

Comment: No, not at all, in the background im using JSON Parse to parse data from a weatherstation, that data can change alot, so i want to update the data in the propertyListview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Your `onTimer` you're adding the object to itself with out changing it.  I would suggest moving the view/container regeneration into a new method.

Then redifine `onTimer` like so:

```
add(new AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(10)) 
{
    @Override
    protected final void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) 
    {   //createContainer() generates the views and container.
        target.add(createContainer()); 
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I would define `createContainer()` like so:

```
private WebMarkupContainer createContainer()
{
  final WeerService weerService = new WeerServiceImpl();

  PropertyListView<Weer> newview = new PropertyListView<Weer>("weer", weerService.getWeer()) 
  {

    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<Weer> item) 
    {
        item.add(new Label("temperatuur"));
        item.add(new StaticImage("type", String.format("images/%s.png", item.getModelObject().getType())));
        item.add(new Label("omschrijving"));
    }
  };

  WeerVoorspellingService weerVoorspellingService = new WeerVoorspellingServiceImpl();

  PropertyListView<WeerVoorspelling> hateView = new PropertyListView<WeerVoorspelling>("weersvoorspelling", weerVoorspellingService.getWeerVoorspelling()) 
  {

    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<WeerVoorspelling> item) 
    {
        item.add(new Label("dag"));
        item.add(new StaticImage("typeVoorspelling", String.format("images/%s.png", item.getModelObject().getType())));
        item.add(new Label("minTemperatuur"));
        item.add(new Label("maxTemperatuur"));
    }
  };

  WebMarkupContainer containerWeer = new WebMarkupContainer("containerWeer");
  containerWeer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
  containerWeer.add(hateView);
  containerWeer.add(newview);
  add(containerWeer);

  return containerWeer;
}
```

**Edited to match final solution**

Then define your `Panel` constructor like so:

```
public WeerPanel(String id) throws IOException 
{
  super(id);

  final WebMarkupContainer container = createContainer();

  add(new AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(10)) 
  {
    @Override
    protected final void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) 
    {   //createContainer() generates the views and container.
        container.addOrReplace(createContainer());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just started Java like 3 weeks ago, hard times for me ;) what do you suggest to put in that method? could you make a small example? Do you also mean the lists?

Comment: Thanx for your reaction ! would give you credits if it wasnt for my low rep.

Comment: still getting a runtime error 

Last cause: A child with id 'containerWeer' already exists:
[WeerPanel [Component id = weer]]

think its because this bit: 

WebMarkupContainer containerWeer = new WebMarkupContainer("containerWeer");
  containerWeer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
  containerWeer.add(hateView);
  containerWeer.add(newview);
  add(containerWeer);

is making the container everytime when the method is called, am i right? :)

Comment: yes every time the method is called a new container is created.
 if you make the `webMarkupContainer` final in your `onTimer` you could call `container.addOrReplace(createContainer());` instead

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the "WeerVoorspelling" once only:

```
PropertyListView<WeerVoorspelling> hateView
  = new PropertyListView<WeerVoorspelling>("weersvoorspelling",
         weerVoorspellingService.getWeerVoorspelling()) { .. }
```

So regardless how the weather forecasts change, your listView still looks at the original list.
You should introduce an indirection:

```
IModel<List<WeerVoorspelling>> weerVoorspelling = new AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<WeerVoorspelling>> {
  public List<WeerVoorspelling> getObject() {
    return weerVoorspellingService.getWeerVoorspelling();
  }
}

PropertyListView<WeerVoorspelling> hateView
  = new PropertyListView<WeerVoorspelling>("weersvoorspelling",
         weerVoorspelling) { .. }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the output in the wicket ajax console, it's probably saying something that a listview cannot be updated directly. Also, can you add the code where you are updating the Listview?

Comment: it looks like it only updating the mark-up file or something, i got the logg if you want to have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

According to the Docs AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior has a method onTimer(). You need to implement this method and add the view you wish to update to the AjaxRequestTarget. This will refresh the component that you wish to update. The ajax event is currently doing nothing at all, which is why you see nothing happening.

Basically, from a high level standpoint, you want to update the backing model object that controls the listView, then when the ajax timer fires, you want to refresh that list to show the latest data.

The code would look something like this:

`containerWeer.add(new AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(5)){
  @Override
  protected final void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    target.addComponent(/The component you wish to refresh/);
  }
});`

Comment: Tried it, but it didnt worked out, see my code if i did it right :)

Comment: Try setting the outputMarkupId on the newWeer component and adding that to the target in the ajax call instead of refreshing the entire component...